# How do I list the items from top form the same line?

Tags: html, css

I want to list some items so I used ul and li tags but when using different amount of li items the structure changes what would be the best solutions for this. Should I use table tag?

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="box1">
    <li>Usefull Links</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>How it works</li>
    <li>Create</li>
    <li>Explore</li>
    <li>Terms & Services</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="box2">
    <li>Community</li>
    <li>Help center</li>
    <li>Partners</li>
    <li>Suggestions</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>News letters</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="box3">
    <li>Partner</li>
    <li>Our Partner</li>
    <li>Become a Partner</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

and the output is like this

[image]

what I actually want is this:-

[image]

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 4 |

Comment: If you don't want to switch to flexbox, then `vertical-align: top` for the `ul` will also do.

Comment: It seems to be a more flexible way (get it ?) to me, I think it should be an answer

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your lists in a wrapper and use Flexbox to give them a proper vertical alignment with the `align-items` property responsible to set the *cross-axis* alignment of the children (the lists, in your example)

```css
.boxes {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
  gap: 2rem;
}

.boxes ul {
  font: 1rem/1.6 system-ui;
  list-style: none;
  flex: 1;
}

.boxes li:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes">
    <ul class="box1">
        <li>Usefull Links</li>
        <li>Content</li>
        <li>How it works</li>
        <li>Create</li>
        <li>Explore</li>
        <li>Terms & Services</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="box2">
        <li>Community</li>
        <li>Help center</li>
        <li>Partners</li>
        <li>Suggestions</li>
        <li>Blog</li>
        <li>News letters</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="box3">
        <li>Partner</li>
        <li>Our Partner</li>
        <li>Become a Partner</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `display:flex` is enough here, the default value of `align-items` is `stretch` which does the work here

Comment: Sure, just wanted to point out what property is controlling the alignment (so in case they could change it if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

just remove `display: inline-block;` from `ul` and apply `display:flex` to `body`

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
ul {
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;

}

ul li:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
body{
display:flex
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <ul class="box1">
    <li>Usefull Links</li>
    <li>Content</li>
    <li>How it works</li>
    <li>Create</li>
    <li>Explore</li>
    <li>Terms & Services</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="box2">
    <li>Community</li>
    <li>Help center</li>
    <li>Partners</li>
    <li>Suggestions</li>
    <li>Blog</li>
    <li>News letters</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="box3">
    <li>Partner</li>
    <li>Our Partner</li>
    <li>Become a Partner</li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add "vertical-align: top" to ul.